# Jump to page in django-tables

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

Just discovered django-tables2 and it's pretty great.  I want to be able to jump to a given page, or jump forward 10 pages, or some sort of improved navigation over going through pages one at a time.  I see that I can easily enter that in the URL, but I'm building this for others that may not be as flexible.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The pagination feature in django-tables2 is using django's built in Paginator class, so you can use any of it's methods and attributes to customize paginator's html output. You just need to [override default template](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#custom-template) and add/change whatever you like into pagination part.

You can also override Paginator class completely:

```
table.paginate(klass=MyPaginator, page=request.GET.get('page', 1), per_page=25)
```

where you can roll your own `MyPaginator` or use 3rd party libraries like [django-pure-pagination](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pure-pagination).